# How to convert microsecond integer into Timestamp with bq load?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

How can I load a csv file into Bigquery using bq load command line tool while converting a microsecond timestamp into bq timestamp?

I'm using the following command:

```
 bq load --skip_leading_rows=1 project1.partition_table "gs://data.csv.gz" ./schema.json
```

When loading this data into a new table with autodetect schema it works but bigquery makes an integer from the microsecond integer.
When trying to add this file to this table it gives the error:

```
Waiting on bqjob_r65c10_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE   
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'skjfafq': Error while reading
data, error message: Could not parse '1611705599779000' as TIMESTAMP for field timestamp (position 2) starting at location 232  with message
'Epoch second value "1611705599779000" out of range'
Failure details:
- Error while reading data, error message: CSV processing encountered
too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error
percent: 0
- query: Could not parse '1611705599779000' as TIMESTAMP for field
timestamp (position 2) starting at location 232  with message
'Epoch second value "1611705599779000" out of range'
- You are loading data without specifying data format, data will be
treated as CSV format by default. If this is not what you mean,
please specify data format by --source_format.
```

Is there a way to directly load files with microsecond timestamp into partitioned (by timestamp) bigquery tables? Or do I first need to load it into a temporary table and convert the value and copy into the partitioned table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the second method you mentioned.

First, load the data into a staging table just with strings then transform it into the timestamp. You can use TIMESTAMP_MICROS(int64_expression) that which is a function in bq itself. Also, something important if you are planning to partition by this field, is that each bq table has a limit of 4, 000 partitions.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions?hl=es_419

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MICROS(1230219000000000) AS timestamp_value;

-- Display of results may differ, depending upon the environment and time zone where this query was executed.
+-------------------------+
| timestamp_value         |
+-------------------------+
| 2008-12-25 15:30:00 UTC |
+-------------------------+
```

Using staging table as I mentioned below, should be something like this:

```
# the expiration flag should delete the table after 1 hour (3600 is the minimum)
# Deleting tables directly from bq command line seems to not be an option
# https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-delete-table 
bq mk --table --expiration 3600 project_id:dataset.temporary_table ./schema.json

# load data from storage into temp table
bq load --skip_leading_rows=1 project_id:dataset.temporary_table 
    "gs://bucket_name/datafile.csv.gz" ./schema.json

# insert data in partitioned table.
bq query 'INSERT `project_id:dataset.complete_table` 
    SELECT timestamp_micros(safe_cast(t1.timestamp as int64)) as timestamp,  
    * except(t1.timestamp) FROM `project_id:dataset.temporary_table` as t1'
```

Comment: Too bad, also because it costs when inserting data but not when using bq load. However do you have an example of what the query would be? I'm trying: insert into `table_1` select TIMESTAMP_MICROS(d.timestamp) as timestamp, d.* except(timestamp) from `table_2` as d. But that runs the query says it inserted but the rows aren't added to the table.

Comment: Firstly, to avoid using insert by stream you can use CTE https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#cte_name , also you can create staging tables, with the transformation that way you won't be using the insert command but creating new staging tables to handle the transformations that would be costless

Comment: But if you want to insert, the commands should be something like:
insert into `pechancourse.examples.sales_example_time` (
  SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP_MICROS(1230219000000000), 0
);

insert into `pechancourse.examples.sales_example_time` (
  ts
) values( TIMESTAMP_MICROS(1230219000000000));

Comment: I edited the answer top including the staging table example.

Comment: Thanks! It turned out the default expiration of partitions was 60 days, so that caused the result to say it inserted the data but it automatically deleted the partitions again ;). I edited your answer a bit to reflect the entire flow